# Access object defined in class to other class

Tags: python

I have two files, `lcd_init.py` and `test.py`. Following is the code in `lcd_init.py` file

```
PINMAP = {
'RS': 7,
'E': 8,
'D0': 25,
'D1': 24,
'D2': 11,
'D3': 9,
'D4': 10,
'D5': 22,
'D6': 27,
'D7': 17,
'CS1': 4,
'CS2': 3,
'RST': 2,
'LED': 18,
}
display = pylcd.ks0108.Display(backend = pylcd.GPIOBackend, pinmap = PINMAP, debug = False)
draw = pylcd.ks0108.DisplayDraw(display)
display.commit(full = True)
```

`display` and `draw` are objects of `Display` and `DisplayDraw` class respectively. How do I access methods of `display` and `draw` object in `test.py` file?

Comment: Using `from lcd_init import display, draw `? Assuming you run it as a module (`python -m test`).

Answer (score 1):

To see all the methods of an object, try `dir(object)`. 
If you know the methods of the class, you can directly call the methods `object.method`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 from lcd_init import display

 display.methodname()
```